# Extinction probability of a branching process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Assume $p$ = probability a gene hit another gene. Such collision would create a new gene that could hit other genes. A collision could create either $3$ or $4$ new genes, each with probability $0.5$. Find maximum value of $p$ so that this branching process would be ensured to die out?

**My attempt:** Let $\pi_0 =$ probability that gene would eventually die out. Then we want $\pi_0=1$ is the solution to the equation: $\pi_0 = p + 0.5p(\pi_0^3+\pi_0^4)$, or $1 = p + p = 2p$. Thus $\fbox{$p=\frac{1}{2}$}$ is the max probability.

**My question:** Could someone please help verify if the above solution is correct?

Comment: No thought about my solution?

Comment: Actually, one wants $\pi_0=1$ to be the $\color{red}{\text{unique}}$ solution of the equation: $\pi_0 = \color{red}{1-p} + \frac12p(\pi_0^3+\pi_0^4)$ (thus, two mistakes).

Comment: @Did: thank you Sir. Hmm, I completely missed the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z$ be the offspring distribution, then 
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Z=0) &= 1-p\\
\mathbb P(Z=3) &= \frac12 p\\
\mathbb P(Z=4) &= \frac12p.\\
\end{align}
Hence 
$$\mu :=\mathbb E[Z] = \frac12p\cdot 3+\frac12p\cdot 4 = \frac72p. $$
The extinction probability is one precisely when $\mu\leqslant 1$, which is the case when $p\leqslant\frac27$.

Comment: This is of course perfectly accurate. One can also correct/complete the OP's generating function approach, see my comment on main. Adding this to your answer would make it even more useful...

Comment: @Did One could, yes. From a pedagogical standpoint, I think that verifying the proposed solution was not correct via a different method is useful as well.

Comment: I disagree. To escape the "I receive a full solution, I copy it and I hand it back to my TA without caring to understand anything in it" syndroma, it is crucial to point specifically the mistakes and/or misconceptions of the solution proposed by the OP. Not to mention that the OP took care to state "My question: Could someone please help verify if the above solution is correct?"

Comment: I personally would use the solution provided to determine the error made in my original attempt myself. I've found that approach to be very helpful in learning to use different techniques to solve problems.

Comment: @Math1000: thank you so much for your hep. I see where my mistake is.

Comment: Cool. $ $ $ $ $ $